# Is there a way to add OneSignal Notification Service Extension from Qt without Xcode

Tags: ios, qt, onesignal

I have an iOS app written using Qt and I want to support OneSignal push notifications.

I know that it can be done by opening builded Qt project in Xcode and then following steps from [iOS SDK Setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup).
The problem is that if I'd like to edit project code for instance from Qt Creator I'd have to rebuild it. After that OneSingle Notification Service Extension configuration will be lost and I'll have to configure it again.

I'm also aware of the Felgo OneSignal plugin (which means I suppose that it's possible to implement such thing in Qt itself) but it's not an option because of price.

So the question is: how to setup OneSignal iOS SDK as well as iOS Notification Service Extension from Qt but not from Xcode?

Comment: Well, adding Frameworks is possible with 'QMAKE_LFLAGS += -framework "MediaPlayer"' e.g. But adding a new capability cannot be achieved within the .pro file. One hacky solution could be to write a post process script which manipulates the xcodeproj file after running "qmake".

Comment: @sk2212, well yes, I think can write such script, but maybe there is another solution.